# How to attach volumes using a template in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to attach few existing volumes using a template in AWS CloudFormation. Is it possible to do it? Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Use `AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment` in your CFN template.

See additional info at

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volumeattachment.html

Comment: Yes, this will work but I have 2 instances and 16 volumes has to be attached in each instance. I've stored all the volume ids in a file. Is there a way so that I can read the volume ids from the files using the template and attached them to the respective instances?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. My approach would be to make a template builder using your language of choice (ruby, java...) that parses the file with ids and generates a proper cloudformation template from a pseudo-template.